# How to manually expire rails low cache by namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

We have:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("google.com/videos", expires_in: 12.hours) { # some request }
Rails.cache.fetch("google.com/images", expires_in: 12.hours) { # some request }
Rails.cache.fetch("stackoverflow.com/questions", expires_in: 12.hours) { # some request }
```

How can I get rails cache be expired by `"google.com"` key or `"stackoverflow.com"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the default cache store, i.e. the [FileStore](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-filestore) or the [MemoryStore](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memorystore), deleting only a subset of keys should be possible with the **[`delete_matched` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/FileStore.html#method-i-delete_matched)**, e.g.:

```
Rails.cache.delete_matched(/^google\.com/)
```

If you are using memcached, it is not possible and you would have to manually delete all keys exactly as used in the `fetch` calls. Or, simply not bother with expiration at all and use keys that change on every relevant change with the data they contain, see e.g. [this blog post](https://quickleft.com/blog/faking-regex-based-cache-keys-in-rails/).